# Linq query with revisioned, nested item generating slow SQL

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-sql

I have a parent child structure in my db like so, in order to track revision changes of my entities:

```
public class orderHeader
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }  
    public bool isDeleted { get; set; } 
}

public class order
{
    public Guid id { get; set; } 
    public Guid orderHeaderId { get; set; }  
    public Guid termHeaderId { get; set; }   
    public string name { get; set; }    
    public string notes{ get; set; }   
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
}

public class termHeader
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }   
}

public class term
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }  
    public string name { get; set; }    
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using linq to query my entities, and I need to be able to give the user the ability to search using both leading and trailing wildcards on both the order string fields, as well as the term string fields.  I also  need to order my results and get a total count for pagination.

My Linq query looks like:

```
string _word = "%123%"
bool _searchOrderName = true;
bool _searchOrderNotes = true;
bool _searchTermName = true;
int _sort = 0;


 var _query = (from tblHeader in _DbContext.orderHeader
              .AsNoTracking()
              .Include(x => x.order.OrderByDescending(x => x.createdOnDate).Take(1))
              .ThenInclude(x => x.termHeader.term.OrderByDescending(x => x.createdOnDate).Take(1))
              where tblHeader.isDeleted != true
              select tblHeader);

if (_searchOrderName)
{
    _query = _query.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.order.OrderByDescending(x => x.createdOnDate).FirstOrDefault().name, _word));
}

if (_searchOrderNotes)
{
    _query = _query.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.order.OrderByDescending(x => x.createdOnDate).FirstOrDefault().notes, _word));
}

if (_searchTermName)
{
    _query = _query.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.order.OrderByDescending(x => x.createdOnDate).FirstOrDefault()
        .termHeader.term.OrderByDescending(x => x.createdOnDate).FirstOrDefault().name, _word));
}

_query = _sort switch
{
    _ => _query.OrderByDescending(x => x.order.OrderByDescending(x => x.createdOnDate).FirstOrDefault().name),
}

var _totalCount = await _query.CountAsync();
```

My problem is that the sql generated by this linq is REALLY slow.  Just this count takes 1.5 seconds, it's generated SQL looks like this:

```
DECLARE @___word_1 AS NVARCHAR(50)='%123%';
SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM [orderHeader] AS [p]
      WHERE (([p].[isDeleted] <> CAST(1 AS bit)) OR ([p].[isDeleted] IS NULL)) 
      AND ((
      ((
          SELECT TOP(1) [p0].[name]
          FROM [order] AS [p0]
          WHERE [p].[id] = [p0].[orderHeaderId]
          ORDER BY [p0].[createdOnDate] DESC) LIKE @___word_1) 
          OR 
          ((
          SELECT TOP(1) [p1].[notes]
          FROM [order] AS [p1]
          WHERE [p].[id] = [p1].[orderHeaderId]
          ORDER BY [p1].[createdOnDate] DESC) LIKE @___word_1)) 
          OR 
          ((
          SELECT TOP(1) [t].[name]
          FROM [term] AS [t]
          WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM [order] AS [p2]
              INNER JOIN [termHeader] AS [t0] ON [p2].[termHeaderId] = [t0].[id]
              WHERE [p].[id] = [p2].[orderHeaderId]) AND ((
              SELECT TOP(1) [t1].[id]
              FROM [order] AS [p3]
              INNER JOIN [termHeader] AS [t1] ON [p3].[termHeaderId] = [t1].[id]
              WHERE [p].[id] = [p3].[orderHeaderId]
              ORDER BY [p3].[createdOnDate] DESC) = [t].[termHeaderId])
          ORDER BY [t].[createdOnDate] DESC) LIKE @___word_1))
```

Whereas I could write sql that executes in .2 - .3 seconds like so:

```
DECLARE @___word_1 AS NVARCHAR(50)='%123%';

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orderHeader

INNER JOIN order
ON order.orderHeaderId = orderHeader.id AND order.id IN     
(SELECT id
    From(
        SELECT id, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY orderHeaderId ORDER BY createdOnDate DESC) orderHeaderId_Rank
        FROM order AS order
    ) AS tbl1
Where tbl1.orderHeaderId_Rank = 1) 

INNER JOIN term as term on term.termHeaderId = order.termHeaderId AND term.id IN
(SELECT id
    From(
   SELECT id, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY termHeaderId ORDER BY createdOnDate DESC) termHeaderId_Rank
   FROM term AS term
    ) AS tbl1
Where tbl1.termHeaderId_Rank = 1)

   where ( 
   ((orderHeader.isDeleted <> CAST(1 AS bit)) OR (orderHeader.isDeleted IS NULL)) AND
   
   (1=2 OR
   order.userfriendlyName Like @___word_1 OR
   order.orderNotes Like @___word_1 OR
   term.userfriendlyName Like @___word_1))
```

I see two problems.

1. Linq is causing a join to the order table for each column being searched, causing the order table to be joined 3 times here for this case.
2. Linq is joining the termHeader as well as the newest term entity, instead of just the newest term.

Is there anyway to imporve performance here?

Comment: So, you have written optimal SQL, which returns less data. Which fields are exactly needed?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv they are both doing a COUNT(*), so no fields are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider to make join to first detail records only once:

```cs
string _word = "%123%"
bool _searchOrderName = true;
bool _searchOrderNotes = true;
bool _searchTermName = true;
int _sort = 0;

var _query = 
    from tblHeader in _DbContext.orderHeader
    from order in tblHeader.order.OrderByDescending(x => x.createdOnDate).Take(1)
    from term in order.termHeader.term.OrderByDescending(x => x.createdOnDate).Take(1)
    where tblHeader.isDeleted != true
    select new 
    {
        tblHeader,
        order,
        term
    };

if (_searchOrderName)
{
    _query = _query.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.order.name, _word));
}

if (_searchOrderNotes)
{
    _query = _query.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.order.notes, _word));
}

if (_searchTermName)
{
    _query = _query.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.term.name, _word));
}

_query = _sort switch
{
    _ => _query.OrderByDescending(x => x.order.name),
}

var _totalCount = await _query.CountAsync();
```